# base de datos y programacion

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Porque me sale este error al intentar abrir phpmyadmin con xampp espero me puedan ayudar es de mucha urgencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta limpiando las cookies de tu phpMyAdmin

Comment: el puerto esta ocupado o mysql no esta UP

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede deberse a que elejiste un idioma no instalado en el menu desplegable de idiomas en pma_lang. Intenta limpiando las cookies de MySQL, principalmente las que empiezan con PMA, entonces podras resetear ese parámetro. No vuelvas a forzar el idioma si no lo tenes instalado, y mantene el idioma por defecto en el menu desplegable de idiomas.

Acá te dejo como borrar las cookies en Chrome y Firefox.

**En google Chrome:**

1. En la barra de herramientas del navegador, haz clic en Más Más y, a
   continuación, Más herramientas y, a continuación, Borrar datos de
   navegación.
2. En el cuadro "Borrar datos de navegación", haz clic en
   las casillas de verificación de Cookies y otros datos de sitios y
   complementos y Archivos e imágenes almacenados en caché.
3. Utiliza el menú situado en la parte superior para seleccionar la cantidad de datos que quieres eliminar. Elige el origen de los tiempos para     eliminarlo todo.
4. Haz clic en Borrar datos de navegación.

**En Firefox**

1. Haz clic en el botón Menú y elige Preferencias.
2. Selecciona el panel Privacidad y seguridad y ve a la sección Historial.
3. En el menú desplegable, junto a Firefox elige la opción Utilizar una configuración personalizada para el histrial.
4. Haz clic en Mostrar Cookies.... Aparecerá la ventana de Cookies.
5. En el campo Buscar escribe el nombre del sitio web cuyas cookies quieras borrar. Se mostrarán las cookies que coincidan con tu búsqueda.
6. Selecciona las cookies de la lista que quieras borrar y haz clic en Eliminar seleccionadas.
7. Haz clic en Cerrar para salir de la ventana Cookies. Cierra la página about:preferences.

Comment: Ok  @LuisDanielRoviraContreras ahi fui mas claro en la solución. Saludos!